# vue-cli webpack sass backgorund image cant be resolved

Tags: node.js, webpack, yarnpkg, vue-cli-4

In my Vue application, I have SCSS file imported to `App.vue` like this:

```html
<style lang="scss">
  @import "@/assets/styles/main.scss";
</style>
```

In my `main.scss` file I have:

```css
background: url(../images/image.png);
```

When I run `yarn build` I'm getting the following error:

> ```
> ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../images/image.png' in '/var/www/project/src'
> ```

I tried to change `url(./images/image.png);` to `url(~/images/image.png);` and error is pretty much the same - just the path to the image is different, like; `'../../../../../../images/image.png`

I tried to install `resolve-url-loader` - that did not help.

My file structure is:

```
.
├── public
│   ├── favicon.iso
│   └── index.html
└── src
    ├── assets
    │   ├── styles
    │   │   └── main.scss
    │   └── images
    │       └── image.png
    ├── main.js
    └── App.vue
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
I tried to move that `background: url(../images/image.png);` outside the sass file and now it looks like

```html
<style lang="scss">
    body {
      background: url("assets/images/FILE1180_1600.JPG");
    }
  @import "@/assets/styles/main.scss";
</style>
```

also, I tried path starting with `./` with `~`, with `@`, with a mix of few of them some times error is that can't resolve and some times the error is `ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)`

Spend the whole day on searching for the solution, looks like I tried all different solution I found on the internet and still not working for me.... :(

Comment: what is most weird for my it's why `url(~/images/image.png);` lead to the path like `'../../../../../../images/image.png`

Answer (score 0):

ooooh, the issue was in the image name, I still not sure what exactly but when I rename it to `backgroun.jpg` it starts working... probably some encoding issue...
But still, it works only when it's outside of the sass file, otherwise, webpack can't find it